# Programming language for GUI compilable to native binary

Tags: user-interface, programming-languages

I need to write an app that reads a config file with info on the menu bars it needs to create.

Normally, I'd just use java, but I need the application to have the least run-time dependencies possible, this includes not forcing the user to download anything, even JRE, let alone something like NET Framework.

So I need something that can compile to an EXE (windows only for now), and that will allow  me to **CODE** the GUI, so I can dynamically create it from my config.

BTW: something like C++ is a bit too low level, all I need is to create menus, and display HTMLs in a panel.

Comment: I suggest you edit your title - there's a difference between "has a runtime" and "interpreted".

Comment: You say that C++ is too "low level", but there is not much in between.  Designing a GUI in C++ isn't that hard really, and it would solve your dependency issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/) together with [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/)?
There is a nice tutorial on how to do it [here](http://wiki.wxpython.org/SmallApp).

Comment: Agreed, I suggested that or GCJ (for Java).

Answer (score 3):

If Java's too high-level and C++ too low-level, there ins't much in-between.  Maybe Delphi?

Comment: The problem with java is not that it's too high level, the problem is it requires JRE to be installed, and my client doesn't want any dependencies.

Comment: A bit heavyweight for displaying a few menus and HTML, isn't it?

Comment: What's lighter -- if C++ (and therefore presumably C) are deemed "too low level"?

Comment: Turbo Explorer (Free Delphi) or Lazarus

But I would go with Delphi in this case because it has some widget to instantiate MSIE for your html.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't totally write off using Java and/or Python for a few reasons.

1) [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) can compile your Python code to an exe.

2) [GCJ](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/) can compile your Java code to an exe.

Comment: +1 for GCJ, if the only problem is the JRE distribution, then maybe the answer is cutting it out of the loop, not switching to an entirely different stack.

Comment: PyInstaller can be an even better way than py2exe (particularly if you use PyQt/Qt, for which it offers special support); but (like, I believe, GCJ) it's still going to make bigger EXEs than Delphi.

Comment: I've tried GCJ before. Regrettably, it still doesn't compile swing applications.

Answer (score 2):

Delphi is best chose for you. Because Delphi compile source code into native x86.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have serious reasons to avoid interpreted languages, I would suggest you better look into ways of packaging or compiling interpreted scripts because doing this will likely reduce your learning and development time.

I would write a simple GUI in **Tcl/Tk**, and then package it as a **[Starpack](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Starpack)**.

ActiveState provides a distribution ([ActiveTCL](https://www.activestate.com/products/tcl/)) and a decent editor ([Komodo Edit](https://www.activestate.com/products/komodo-edit/)), and it is fairly easy to get simple GUIs going with Tk. Check out [TkDocs](https://tkdocs.com/index.html) for some hand holding.

Once you're done, you can [package](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Starpack) your code,  a Tcl runtime, a database, and a virtual filesystem, all into a single executable that you can easily distribute.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [D](http://digitalmars.com/d/) ? It has a syntax that is like a mixture of Java, C++ and Python with the ability to make native windows apps. The tutorials on [dprogramming.com](http://www.dprogramming.com/) are great to get up and going with the language. For quick GUIs you'd be interested in [The D Forms Library](http://www.dprogramming.com/dfl.php) and the [Entice Designer](http://www.dprogramming.com/entice.php).

[Here](http://www.dprogramming.com/dfl/videos.php) are some short video tutorials to get up and running with Entice.

Alternatively, have you tried [Qt & Qt Creator](http://trolltech.com)? It takes a lot of the hair pulling out of C++ Programming and it's also cross-platform.

Comment: I'm giving both your suggestions a try, and as I go along, I'll decide which one I'll keep. :)

Comment: Is there a free version that allows to link everything into one QT binary? Otherwise QT is a ... runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Earwicker is right.  You can use HTA:
http://www.interclasse.com/scripts/htanotepad.php

But if you know C++, then creating this type of an application is actually very easy with Visual C++.  Use MFC, and statically link everything.   You can draw the menu in the resource editor, and attach events to the menu items.  I wouldn't use HTML if I were you.  Just use regular Windows controls.   But if you're really set on using HTML, you can embed a Browser control in the formview.

Comment: I need to create the menus dynamicaly from the file I read, so C++ would mean i'd have to read the file, parse it, and hand code the menu-generation, I can't drawn it, since it's only known at run-time.
BTW: I strictly need to use MenuBars, can't use some other type of menus.

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> all I need is to create menus, and
>   display HTMLs in a panel.

A lot like a Web browser, then. If it's going to run on Windows, then the user has IE. Why not use IE to do all the work for you?

You can make something a lot like an .exe with IE, called an .hta:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496(VS.85).aspx

Comment: The menus must be [not realy by my own choice] menuBars.
Also, handling the menu generation in HTA seems a little far too compliated, since i need to read and parse the file as well.. I haven't looked in into TOOOO much detail, but that's my first-hand impresion

Comment: Can you decide the format of the "config file" for the menus? How about making the format be HTML?

Comment: Nope, not up to me.
Even though I could parse it, an create an HTML with some other tool, the client insist on a menubar (very much a windows one)